# can't add geom_hline() with dataset of different length

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add to a barchart with a horizontal line to separate the filling region. I use the following codes and that works fine.

```
bar1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(1), fill = factor(cyl))) + geom_bar(width = 1)
tbl = cumsum(table(mtcars$cyl))
bar1 + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = tbl[1:2]), color = 'white', size=2) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = tail(tbl, 1)), color = 'white', size = 2 )
```

However, if I merge the two `geom_hline()` methods into one, there is an error.

```
bar1 + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = tbl), color = 'white', size=2)
# Error in data.frame(yintercept = c(11L, 7L, 14L), PANEL = c(1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
#                             arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 32
```

Why couldn't I just use `geom_hline` to plot 3 horizontal lines in method call?

Comment: is there really enough information here to support an answer?

Comment: I wonder whether there are more generic way to add more horizontal lines .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
bar1 = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(1), fill = factor(cyl))) + geom_bar(width = 1)
tbl = cumsum(table(mtcars$cyl))
bar1 + geom_hline(data=data.frame(tbl), aes(yintercept = tbl), color = 'white', size=2)
```

[image]

Comment: So _that's_ what was being asked!